# Adding associated entities in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity *Person* and an entity *Team*. Logically Person and Team have a *ManyToMany* relationship. But because I have an additional attribute, the role of the person in the team, that qualifies the relation, I have to model the relation as two relations to a join-entity, which I called *PersonToTeam*. Here is the code:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.person", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<PersonToTeam> teamAssociations = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Team {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.team", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<PersonToTeam> teamAssociations = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class PersonToTeam {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonToTeamId id = new PersonToTeamId();
    private RoleInTeam role;

    public enum RoleInTeam {
        ADMIN, MEMBER
    }
}

public class PersonToTeamId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8450195271351341722L;
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
    @ManyToOne
    private Team team;
}
```

So far so good. But what I do not like is the effort to add an admin to a team. This looks like:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setId("d022051");
person.setName("Gregor Frey");
personRepo.save(person);

Team team = new Team();
team.setId("SpringTutorial");
team.setName("Spring Tutorial");

PersonToTeam assoc = new PersonToTeam();
assoc.getId().setPerson(person);
assoc.getId().setTeam(team);
assoc.setRole(RoleInTeam.ADMIN);

List<PersonToTeam> teamAssociations = person.getTeamAssociations();
teamAssociations.add(assoc);
List<PersonToTeam> personAssociations = team.getTeamAssociations();
personAssociations.add(assoc);

teamRepo.save(team);
```

I would like to have a method *addAdminToTeam* which takes a person, creates a new personToTeam association and adds it to the set of of associated persons in the team.

My question is: where should I put this method? In the entity, as a transient setter? In the repository (is that possible at all)? Or in a separate service object? Are there other ways to simplify the procedure?

Comment: Your question is more around basic encapsulation than JPA.  To ensure the correctness of the data model at any single point in time encapsulate the operations in the Entity and return Iterator/unmodifiable collections for the associations in order that  client classes are forced through these methods. Client code will never then be able to get the  model in an inconsistent state i.e. by setting one side of the relationship without setting the other.

Answer (score 1):

In my advice you should create a repository layer in which you can put all the "repository" logic. In this layer you should put all the CRUD methods (DAO) and all other methods that you want related to your entity and inter entity like DCS (Data Control Service Pattern).

In this way you can have a single repository responsibility class, without scattering your DB logic in your service layer.

This should be read as an advice of architectural styling, and this is a valid choice because in your code tract only presistance logic and not business logic.

The music change if your addAdminToTeam  method has to perform more work then impact your business logic. For security logging and so on you can rely on Spring AOP but for other commitments you should think about a service layer. However in your case I consider that a repository layer as described above is the best solution. For the setter option in my opinion isn't a good choice because you create a tightly coupled implementation of a persistence thing in your domain object, and for the procedure you scattering the logic across the your java code and the code that run in your database.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tend to agree to put the data access logic in the repository, and keep the persistence layer free from anything but the data model. But I wonder, can I add a method like addPersonAsAdmin to the team repository as a JPARepository=

Comment: Yess it is possible. For add custom method in your repository exist a strategy described in the documentation on link:http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html chapter 4.6, I use it in a my open source project you can see the detail on link: https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary/tree/master/book-metadata-service/src/main/java/it/valeriovaudi/documentlibrary/repository. For update query your methos should be annotated with @Modifying described in the chapter 5.3.7

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is, that Spring Data Rest does not take into account such custom methods. If I model the admins as a transient attribute of the team, Spring Data Rest will show the admins as a sub-resource of the team.

Comment: Ok but I didn't know that your focus was on Spring Data Rest because the post was for Spring Data.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's just to convey the context of the question. Your answer is very valid. And I like the clear separation of concerns. It's just that custom repository extensions are from a rest point of view not seamlessly integrated.